# JSF 2:How include style sheets and javascript?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

i'm having a strange problem,
if my page index.xhml is:

```
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <head>
    //.. import css and javascript
    </head>
    <body>
    // .. my page content
    </body>
</html>
```

Everthing is okay, but, if i change to `<head>` to `<h:head>` and `<body>` to `</h:body>` my page it seems not apply the style very well, as far i can tell it seems my javascript file is not been applied in the page.
Why this happen ? I already try change to `<h:outputScript library="javascript" name="file.js" />` but it doesn't work either.

Any idea ? Why this is happening ?

Comment: How have you setup the mapping of the FacesServlet in your web.xml? I suspect you are using the wrong url to see the page. For example, if the mapping is <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> you should be using http://example.com/app/index.jsf to have you page parsed properly.

Comment: Hi Giorgos, my page is parsed properly, but are my javascripts that's not.

Comment: If you view the page source in the browser are the JS and CSS bits been rendered by JSF ?

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the exact syntax of your source file and the rendered page? Then we could make more informed guesses.

I also suggest to use the web developer tools of Chromium. There you can check if your resources are loaded properly.

Comment: the solution to my problem is here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928298/custom-css-doesnt-get-applied-when-using-hhead-instead-of-head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this above body and then u can use the methods directly in your jsp

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/yourJSFile.js" type="text/javascript"/>

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/yourCSSFile.css"    type="text/css" />
```

yourJS.js yourCSS.css file should be under your WebContent(${pageContext.request.contextPath}) .
Its better to maintain seperate folder for your js,css,pages etc.