# Custom CSS doesn't get applied when using <h:head> instead of <head>

Tags: java, css, jsf, jsf-2

if I put:

```
<head>
//..
</head>

<body>
//..
</body>
```

The style from my CSS is applied correctly, but when I change to :

```
<h:head>
//..
</h:head>

<h:body>
//..
</h:body>
```

My style it seems wrong some parts of CSS.

Why this is happenning ?

**Update:**
To simplify my problem i'm show two images below:

Without

> `<h:head>.. <h:body>` (this is the correct CSS style)

[image: Okay]

With

```
<h:head>..<h:body>
```

[image: With error]

I just change  to  and the same thing to  and this error happens.

I'm new about JSF, there's something that i have to do ?

**Update 2:**
I'm using Rich Faces 4, one thing that i realized was that appears one script include in the end of  tag:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/brainset/rfRes/skinning.ecss.xhtml?db=eAHL6rC8BQAEkAIG">
```

I didn't put that, and this only appears with

```
> <h:head> ... <h:body>
```

tags.
I think that my style is overridden by RichFaces include this 'skinning.ecss'.

Comment: there should be no problem. Can you add the generated html and the css rule you're trying to apply? Probably the `FacesServlet` is not processing the view and the resulting tags are being `<h:head />` and `<h:body />`. Maybe you should check the url mapping of the `FacesServlet`

Comment: Why are you hijacking the stackoverflow's favicon? Anyway, you really need to be more clear about the concrete problem. What happens? What happens not? Elaborate in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. **What exactly** do you mean with *"My style it seems wrong some parts of CSS."*? What do developer tools like Firebug say about this?

Comment: @BalusC, "Why are you hijacking the stackoverflow's favicon?" : is just some tests that i'm doing, but i'm not gonna use stack overflow favicon, you can be cool about that ;).
"What happens not?" : The CSS is applied in the hole site but i have this problem, the name of the company descreases and i don't know why this happens, it should be normal as it was with <head> <body>tags.
"What exactly do you mean with "My style it seems wrong some parts of CSS."? : the style is applied in the site, but not in this part, as you can see in the pictures that i put in the post.

Comment: As per your screenshots, JSF is working perfectly fine. Your problem is in the CSS. What CSS got applied and what not? Are you using a rich UI component library such as PrimeFaces for which you would need to override its default styles? You can check that with for example Firebug. Rightclick the element of interest and choose *Inspect Element*. On the right hand side you see all CSS what got applied/overriden. You can toggle and edit it over there.

Comment: @BaluC, i'm using RichFaces 4.

Comment: OK, now what properties of your CSS got overriden by RichFaces? Firebug should tell you that. Then add `!important` to exactly those properties of your CSS.

Comment: @BalusC, it was RichFaces that was overridden my style, mate, thanks by the tip.

Comment: You should post the answer as an answer, not as part of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RichFaces 4 was overridden my style,so to disable skinning we have to use parameters as below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>plain</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And this solve my problem ;)

[Source](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/nightly_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/#sect-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming-Skinning_standard_controls)

Comment: you should accept the answer if it solved your problem. Read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @bluefoot: I didn't read it. It was just some sarcasm which you deserved ;)

Comment: that was funny BalusC and bluefoot ;)